# Angular form validation highlight issue

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, phpstorm, angular2-forms

I have this form :

```
<form #createTeamForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="createTeam(createTeamForm)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="newTeam">{{ "teams.createTeam" | translate }}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newTeam" name="newTeam" ngModel #newTeam="ngModel" placeholder="{{'words.name' | translate}}" required minlength="3">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="createTeamForm.submitted && !newTeam.valid">
            <div *ngIf="newTeam.errors.required">
                First name is required.
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="newTeam.errors.minlength">
                First name should be minimum {{ newTeam.errors.minlength.requiredLength }} characters.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{{ "words.send" | translate }}</button>
</form>
```

The `newTeam.errors.required` and `newTeam.errors.minlength` are highlighted as errors in TypeScript using WebStorm : `Angular: Identifier 'minlength' is not defined. '__type' does not contain such a member`

I don't get why and don't find how to fix this. The code is working properly, the errors are displayed as needed.

[EDIT] - submitted a bug report to IntelliJ, I'm pretty sure it's coming from there

Comment: Show us your Component, specifically where `newTeam.errors` is defined: you've tagged the question `typescript` but haven't shown any, and that's where the problem is ;)

Comment: Thanks for answering :) I actually tagged `typescript` because the highlight looked like being linked to it but I may have been wrong. Since it's an Angular template driven form, there is no explicit definition of newTeam.errors in the Component, it's automatically initialized by Angular itself. Also, it works perfectly. Only the highlight is faulty, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from Angular language service and, as such, has to be reported to [Angular team](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues). Issues that look similar: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15460, https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/126